# Scala cats trampoline

Tags: scala, scala-cats, trampolines

The test("ok") is copied from book "scala with cats" by Noel Welsh and Dave Gurnell pag.254 ("D.4 Safer Folding using Eval
"), the code run fine, it's the trampolined foldRight

```
import cats.Eval
test("ok") {
val list = (1 to 100000).toList


def foldRightEval[A, B](as: List[A], acc: Eval[B])(fn: (A, Eval[B]) => Eval[B]): Eval[B] =
  as match {
    case head :: tail =>
      Eval.defer(fn(head, foldRightEval(tail, acc)(fn)))
    case Nil =>
      acc
  }

def foldRight[A, B](as: List[A], acc: B)(fn: (A, B) => B): B =
  foldRightEval(as, Eval.now(acc)) { (a, b) =>
    b.map(fn(a, _))
  }.value

val res = foldRight(list, 0L)(_ + _)

assert(res == 5000050000l)
}
```

The test("ko") returns same values of test("ok") for small list but for long list the value is different. Why?

```
test("ko") {
val list = (1 to 100000).toList

def foldRightSafer[A, B](as: List[A], acc: B)(fn: (A, B) => B): Eval[B] = as match {
  case head :: tail =>
    Eval.defer(foldRightSafer(tail, acc)(fn)).map(fn(head, _))
  case Nil => Eval.now(acc)
}

val res = foldRightSafer(list, 0)((a, b) => a + b).value

assert(res == 5000050000l)
}
```

Comment: `foldRightSafer(list, 0)` is folding to `Int`, not to `Long`. Should be `0L`

Comment: Trivial typo. The OP forgot a single 'L' in '0L', and got an integer instead of a long.

Answer (score 1):

*This is @OlegPyzhcov's comment, converted into a community wiki answer*

You forgot the `L` in `0L` passed as second argument to `foldRightSafer`.
Because of that, the inferred generic types of the invocation are

```
foldRightSafer[Int, Int]((list : List[Int]), (0: Int))((_: Int) + (_: Int))
```

and so your addition overflows and gives you something smaller than 2000000000 (9 zeroes, `Int.MaxValue = 2147483647`).